Offline Detector in Nextjs
I am trying to write an util function that checks if the user is connected to internet or not, not when connected to a network.
I used this below but it only work when user is connected to a network, if I turn off the internet of the network it would still be connected because the navigator.onLine works on a network:
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const OfflineDetector = () => {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(false); 

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOnline(navigator?.onLine); 

    const handleOnline = () => setIsOnline(true);
    const handleOffline = () => setIsOnline(false);

    window.addEventListener("online", handleOnline);
    window.addEventListener("offline", handleOffline);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("online", handleOnline);
      window.removeEventListener("offline", handleOffline);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!isOnline && (
        <p className="bg-red-500 text-center text-white">
          You are currently offline. Please check your internet connection.
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

So I have tried to make a fetch to a reliable url but it's not working as expected:
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const OfflineDetector = () => {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(true); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkInternetConnection = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://www.google.com/favicon.ico", {
          method: "HEAD",
          cache: "no-cache",
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          setIsOnline(true);
        } else {
          setIsOnline(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setIsOnline(false);
      }
    };

    const handleOnline = () => {
      checkInternetConnection();
    };

    const handleOffline = () => {
      setIsOnline(false);
    };

    // Initial check
    checkInternetConnection();

    window.addEventListener("online", handleOnline);
    window.addEventListener("offline", handleOffline);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("online", handleOnline);
      window.removeEventListener("offline", handleOffline);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!isOnline && (
        <p className="bg-red-500 text-center text-white">
          You are currently offline. Please check your internet connection.
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

